# How to get channel data directly from ArrayBuffer without Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

In my web application I'm using HTML5 Audio for audio playback. But because I need the channelData of the audio file, I need to do the following steps when the application starts:

1. Decode ArrayBuffer to AudioBuffer using Web Audio API
2. Call audioBuffer.getChannelData(0)
3. Process channelData and dump the audioBuffer
4. With the channelData I can draw the audio signal to a canvas

Is there any way that enables to calculate the channelData from raw data (ArrayBuffer)? My application only supports WAVE with PCM 16 Bit.

I know the structure of the WAVE format and how to read values from raw data via Javascript, but I don't understand how `getChannelData()` calculates its values. I found nothing about it online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing magical about `getChannelData`; it just returns the data from an `AudioBuffer`.  If you have a 16-bit PCM WAV file, you decode it easily into 16-bit PCM values in Javascript.  To get what `getChannelData` would have produced, take that 16-bit value and divide by 32768 to get a floating-point value between -1 and 1.

Comment: thank you very much! I tested it and I get slightly differrent values when I compare it: Such as:
Sample 1: 
From Raw: 0.00341796875
From Web API: 0.0033789610024541616

Sample 2: 
From Raw: 0.005035400390625
From Web API: 0.005054975859820843

and so on. Do you know why the values are not equal? Does it have something to do with the Browser's sampling rate?

Comment: It could be.  If the sample rate of the WAV file is the same as the context, then they should match.  If the rates are different `decodeAudioData` will resample the audio file to match the context sample rate.  Oh, one last thing,  It might be that for positive PCM values, divide by 32767 and for negative values divide by 32768, since the 16-bit values lie between -32768 and 32767.